# Get Multiple value from Multiple table in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I just make a music online 's website . But I stuck when try to get all the track , playlist ,album created by user order by time created . I have 4 table including : user,track,album,playlist look like this :

```
+---------------+------------------+
| Field         | Type             | 
+---------------+------------------+
| album_id      | int(10) unsigned |
| user_id       | int(10) unsigned |
| album_title   | varchar(255)     |
| album_created | datetime()       |

+---------------+------------------+
| Field         | Type             | 
+---------------+------------------+
| playlist_id   | int(10) unsigned |
| user_id       | int(10) unsigned |
| playlist_title| varchar(255)     |
| plist_created | datetime()       |

+---------------+------------------+
| Field         | Type             | 
+---------------+------------------+
| track_id      | int(10) unsigned |
| user_id       | int(10) unsigned |
| track_title   | varchar(255)     |
| track_created | datetime()       |

+---------------+------------------+
| Field         | Type             | 
+---------------+------------------+
| user_id      | int(10) unsigned |
| user_name    | varchar(255      |
| password     | varchar(255)     |
| email        | varchar(255      |
```

Here is my code , but it just get all the track ,album,playlist in 1 array

```
return Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('u.*,t.*,p.*,a.*')
        ->from('user u ')
        ->join('track t', 'u.user_id = s.user_id')
        ->leftjoin('playlist p', 'u.user_id = p.user_id')
        ->leftjoin('album a', 'u.user_id = a.user_id')
        ->andWhere('t.user_id ='.$id.' OR a.user_id ='.$id.' OR p.user_id ='.$id )
        ->queryAll();
```

I want result like this example :

```
[0] => array([album_id] => 11 , [user_id] => 1 , [album_title] => aaa ,[album_created] => 2014-06-03 )
[1] => array([song_id] => 13 , [user_id] => 1 , [song_title] => aaa ,[song_created] => 2014-06-02 )
[2] => array([song_id] => 22 , [user_id] => 1 , [song_title] => zyx ,[song_created] => 2014-05-30 )
[3] => array([playlist_id] => 1 , [user_id] => 1 , [playlist_title] => xxxx ,[playlist_created] => 2014-05-25 )
```

Comment: why `OR` try using `AND`

Comment: it still get all the value from track,playlist,album table into an array. Bui i want in every array it get value from 1 table base on time created track/album/playlist

Comment: can you show how the output coming present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired output, what you need is a [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) of track, playlist and album that looks something like:

```
   id   |   user_id   |   type   |   title   |   created   
--------|-------------|----------|-----------|-----------
```

`type` is either `album`, `playlist` or `song` in your case. This can be achieved using [`CDbCommand::union()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#union%28%29-detail) and [`CDbCommand::getText()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#getText%28%29-detail) as follows:

```
return Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select("a.album_id, a.user_id, 'Album' as type, a.album_title, a.album_created as created")
    ->from('album a')
    ->andWhere('a.user_id ='.$id)
    ->union(
        Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select("s.song_id, s.user_id, 'Song' as type, s.song_title, s.song_created as created")
            ->from('song s')
            ->andWhere('s.user_id ='.$id)
            ->getText()
    )->union(
        Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select("p.playlist_id, p.user_id, 'Playlist' as type, p.playlist_title, p.plist_created as created")
            ->from('playlist p')
            ->andWhere('p.user_id ='.$id)
            ->getText()
    )->queryAll();
```

To make life easier, you should make a view from the union. With a bit of tweaking you may be able to use `CActiveRecord` (and therefore `relations()` and `CActiveDataProvider`) together with this view.

Answer (score 0):

```
->select('u.*,t.*,p.*,a.*')
    ->from('user u ')
    ->join('track t', 'u.user_id = t.user_id')
    ->leftjoin('playlist p', 'u.user_id = p.user_id')
    ->leftjoin('album a', 'u.user_id = a.user_id')
    ->andWhere('t.user_id ='.$id.' AND u.user_id ='.$id.' AND a.user_id ='.$id.' AND p.user_id ='.$id )
```

->order('a.album_created, p.plist_created, t.track_created')
        ->queryAll();